# Retrofit with Simpleframework XML

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit, simple-framework

I'm using retrofit to connect to my API and trying to parse messages with Simpleframework XML, but I keep getting the error below:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'head' does not have a match in class Classes at line 5
```

Here are my classes and XML that I should be getting but Im connecting to an Microsoft asmx service and its returning the html above http://pastebin.com/ASvV0Cwq, somewhere in the soap envelope should be the xml body

```
@Root(name = "tables")
public class Classes
{
   @ElementList(name = "tables", inline = true)
   List<MyClass> tables;
}
```

:

```
Root(name="table")

public class MyClass implements Serializable
{
    @Element(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Element(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Element(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @Element(name = "key")
    private String key;
}
```

This should be the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tables>
   <table>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Admin</name>
      <value>111</value>
      <key>999</key>
   </table>
   <table>
      <id>5</id>
      <name>Bari Limani</name>
      <value>121</value>
      <key>999</key>
</tables>
```

Comment: hmmm error seems to be obvious ... your xml doesn't look in the way you've shown ... pretty much it's starts from `<head>` ... maybe you are not getting xml at all ... but html(with some error) ...

Comment: @Selvin You are right this is the HTML Im getting http://pastebin.com/ASvV0Cwq

Comment: @Selvin I updated my question

Comment: seems like you are hitting wrong url ... prolly service's discovery url instead service's method url ...

Comment: @Selvin I don't understand you :(

Answer (score 0):

An end table tag is missing in the XML.